# cannot my customers checkout in my checkout page

Tags: checkout

## my customers can't checkout in my site

I have a problem in my site,my customers can not check out .
when they click on checkout button not happened
pls help me

https://www.roblixshop.com/checkout/onepage/

Comment: Most users here will not be able to get to the checkout on an Arabic site so your link will not help a lot. Check log files and the developer console to find any errors related to this

Answer (score 1):

you have following error message check the file **`(Smsservice.php)`** missing.. check the `var/log` for more detail about error

```
<br />
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  main(): Failed opening required 'Smsservice.php' (include_path='/home/roblixsh/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php55/pear') in <b>/home/roblixsh/public_html/includes/src/MagentoFarsi_SMSNotifyForMagento_Model_Service.php</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```